# What does "copious visage" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning

What does "copious visage" mean? It's not a typical usage of the word "copious". None of Wiktionary's meanings for the word seem to fit. Wells's Invisible Man

> You must picture Mr. Thomas Marvel as a person of **copious, flexible visage**, a nose of cylindrical protrusion, a liquorish, ample, fluctuating mouth, and a beard of bristling eccentricity.

Answer (score 2):

The wording, though unusual in this combination, is meant literally. Look up "visage", "flexible" and "copious". The consider the nose, "a **flexible** protrusion", "**ample** mouth" and you'll find the meaning consonant with those phrases.

Comment: In what sense is "copious" used here?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev large in quantity.

Comment: How can visage (face expression) be "large in quantity"?